# Positional argument error when trying to train SGDClassifier on binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, gradient-descent

I'm working through [Aurelien Geron's Hands-On ML textbook](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml) and have got stuck trying to train an SGDClassifier.

I'm using the MNIST handwritten numbers data and running my code in a Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda. Both my anaconda (1.7.0) and sklearn (0.20.dev0) are updated. I've pasted the code I used to load the data, select the first 60k rows, shuffle the order and convert the labels to 1 (True) for all 5's and 0 (False) for all other numbers. Both X_train and y_train_5 are numpy arrays.

I've pasted the error message I get below.

Nothing seems to be wrong with the dimensions of the data, I tried converting X_train to a sparse matrix (the suggested format for SGDClassifier) and various max_iter values and got the same error message each time. Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to use a different version of sklearn? I've searched online but couldn't find any posts describing similar issues with SGDClassifier. I'd be super grateful for any kind of pointer.

**Code**

```
from six.moves import urllib
from scipy.io import loadmat
import  numpy as np
from  sklearn.linear_model  import SGDClassifier


# Load MNIST data #

from scipy.io import loadmat
mnist_alternative_url = "https://github.com/amplab/datascience- 
sp14/raw/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat"
mnist_path = "./mnist-original.mat"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(mnist_alternative_url)
with open(mnist_path, "wb") as f:
    content = response.read()
    f.write(content)
mnist_raw = loadmat(mnist_path)
mnist = {
    "data": mnist_raw["data"].T,
    "target": mnist_raw["label"][0],
    "COL_NAMES": ["label", "data"],
    "DESCR": "mldata.org dataset: mnist-original",
}


# Assign X and y #

X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']


# Select first 60000 numbers #

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], 
y[60000:]


# Shuffle order #

shuffle_index  = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]


# Convert labels to binary (5 or "not 5") #

y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

# Train SGDClassifier #

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(max_iter=5, random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

**Error Message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5a25eed28833> in <module>()
     37 # Train SGDClassifier
     38 sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(max_iter=5, random_state=42)
---> 39 sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
712                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
713                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
--> 714                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    715 
    716 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    570 
    571         self._partial_fit(X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, self._max_iter,
--> 572                           classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    573 
    574         if (self._tol is not None and self._tol > -np.inf

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _partial_fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, max_iter, classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    529                              learning_rate=learning_rate,
    530                              sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 531                              max_iter=max_iter)
    532         else:
    533             raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _fit_binary(self, X, y, alpha, C, sample_weight, learning_rate, max_iter)
    587                                               self._expanded_class_weight[1],
    588                                               self._expanded_class_weight[0],
--> 589                                               sample_weight)
    590 
    591         self.t_ += n_iter_ * X.shape[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in fit_binary(est, i, X, y, alpha, C, learning_rate, max_iter, pos_weight, neg_weight, sample_weight)
    419                            pos_weight, neg_weight,
    420                            learning_rate_type, est.eta0,
--> 421                            est.power_t, est.t_, intercept_decay)
    422 
    423     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\sgd_fast.pyx in sklearn.linear_model.sgd_fast.plain_sgd()

TypeError: plain_sgd() takes at most 21 positional arguments (25 given)
```

Comment: It looks like you've somehow got a mismatch between the pure Python (.py) and compiled Cython (.pyx) parts of `sklearn`. Because [`plain_sgd`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/dd700f44dfe2fedee2e877b829eeee0dfd8b9eb4/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L335) does take 25 argments, as of the latest version.

Comment: What do you get if you run `pip freeze | grep scikit`? You could try updating your scikit with `pip install -U scikit-learn`. I just did exactly that and your code ran fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your version of `scikit-learn` is just a little outdated. Try running:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

then your code will run (with some slight formatting updates):

```
from six.moves import urllib
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model  import SGDClassifier
from scipy.io import loadmat

# Load MNIST data #
mnist_alternative_url = "https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/raw/master/lab7/mldata/mnist-original.mat"
mnist_path = "./mnist-original.mat"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(mnist_alternative_url)
with open(mnist_path, "wb") as f:
  content = response.read()
  f.write(content)
mnist_raw = loadmat(mnist_path)
mnist = {
  "data": mnist_raw["data"].T,
  "target": mnist_raw["label"][0],
  "COL_NAMES": ["label", "data"],
  "DESCR": "mldata.org dataset: mnist-original",
}

# Assign X and y #
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']

# Select first 60000 numbers #
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]

# Shuffle order #
shuffle_index  = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

# Convert labels to binary (5 or "not 5") #
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

# Train SGDClassifier #
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(max_iter=5, random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

Comment: Thanks! Updating the scikit-learn package worked. Since I'm using anaconda, I had to use the following command (in case some other anaconda user stumbles across this thread in future) >> conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn

Comment: @IsabelHutchison amen!